# Convert an irregular time series M-D-Y hh:mm:ss to regular TS filling with NA

Tags: r, date, time, time-series

I had read previous post but I cannot obtain that I want. I need to obtain a serie with 16 intervals by day (least the first and last day, in these cases the intervals start/end with the first/last observation). I would like that the observed variables are located in the corresponding inteval and NA otherwise.

My data look as follows: [Ya and Yb are the observed variables]

```
mdyhms                  Ya  Yb
Mar-27-2009 19:56:47    25  58.25
Mar-27-2009 20:38:59    9   81.25
Mar-28-2009 08:00:30    9   88.75
Mar-28-2009 09:26:29    0   89.25
Mar-28-2009 11:57:01    8.5 74.25
Mar-28-2009 12:19:10    7.5 71.00
Mar-28-2009 14:17:05    1.5 70.00
Mar-28-2009 15:13:14    NA  NA
Mar-28-2009 17:09:53    4   85.50
Mar-28-2009 18:37:24    0   86.00
Mar-28-2009 19:19:23    0   50.50
Mar-28-2009 20:45:50    0   36.25
Mar-29-2009 08:44:16    4.5 34.50
Mar-29-2009 10:35:12    8.5 39.50
Mar-29-2009 11:09:13    3.67    69.00
Mar-29-2009 12:40:07    0   54.25
Mar-29-2009 14:31:48    5.33    35.75
Mar-29-2009 16:19:27    6.33    71.75
Mar-29-2009 16:43:20    7.5 64.75
Mar-29-2009 18:37:42    8   83.75
Mar-29-2009 20:01:26    6.17    93.75
Mar-29-2009 20:43:53    NA  NA
Mar-30-2009 08:42:05    12.67   88.50
Mar-30-2009 09:52:57    4.33    75.50
Mar-30-2009 12:01:32    1.83    70.75
Mar-30-2009 12:19:40    NA  NA
Mar-30-2009 14:23:37    3.83    86.75
Mar-30-2009 16:00:59    37.33   80.25
Mar-30-2009 17:19:28    10.17   77.75
Mar-30-2009 17:49:12    9.83    73.00
Mar-30-2009 20:06:00    11.17   76.75
Mar-30-2009 21:40:35    20.33   68.25
Mar-31-2009 08:11:12    18.33   69.75
Mar-31-2009 09:51:29    14.5    65.50
Mar-31-2009 11:10:41    NA  NA
Mar-31-2009 13:27:09    NA  NA
Mar-31-2009 13:44:35    NA  NA
Mar-31-2009 16:01:23    NA  NA
Mar-31-2009 16:56:14    NA  NA
Mar-31-2009 18:27:28    NA  NA
Mar-31-2009 19:17:46    NA  NA
Mar-31-2009 21:12:22    NA  NA
Apr-01-2009 08:35:24    2.33    60.25
Apr-01-2009 09:24:49    1.33    71.50
Apr-01-2009 11:28:34    5.67    62.00
Apr-01-2009 13:31:48    NA  NA
Apr-01-2009 14:52:18    NA  NA
Apr-01-2009 15:11:44    1.5 71.50
Apr-01-2009 17:00:53    3.17    84.00
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use the `dput` function on your object ( `dput(foo)` ) and copy the output? That allows us to read the data easier

Comment: Thanks Marek to edit my data, now I know how to do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming your dataframe is called "Data", I'd use [xts package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html). They're a whole lot easier to work with :

```
#Conversion of dates
Data$time <- as.POSIXct(Data$mdyhms,format="%b-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")

#conversion to time series
library(xts)
TimeSeries <- xts(Data[,c("Ya","Yb")],Data[,"time"])
```

Then TimeSeries can be used subsequently. You can't use a normal ts, because you don't have a regular time series. No way on earth you can defend that the time intervals between your observations are equal.

EDIT :

In regard of your remarks in the comments, you can try the following :

```
#Calculate the period they're into
#This is based on GMT and the fact that POSIXct gives the number of seconds
#passed since the origin. 5400 is 1/16 of 86400 seconds in a day

Data$mdyhms <- as.POSIXct(Data$mdyhms,format="%b-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="GMT")
Data$Period <- as.numeric(Data$mdyhms) %/% 5400 * 5400

#Make a new data frame with all periods in the range of the dataframe

Date <- as.numeric(trunc(Data$mdyhms,"day"))
nData <- data.frame(
    Period = seq(min(Date),max(Date)+86399,by=5400)
)
# Merge both dataframes and take the mean of values within a dataframe

nData <- merge(Data[c('Ya','Yb','Period')],nData,by="Period",all=T)
nData <- ddply(nData,"Period",mean,na.rm=T)

#Make the time series and get rid of the NaN values
#These come from averaging vectors with only NA
TS <- ts(nData[c('Ya','Yb')],frequency=16)
TS[is.nan(TS)] <- NA
```

Comment: @Joris Meys Joris, I agree with you with regard to the characteristics of these observations. Beyond of this, I would like that the observed variables are located in the corresponding interval (16 by day) and NA otherwise (this is my OBJECTIVE). By other hand, when I apply your proposal I obtain this error:  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. Thanks!

Comment: @Erica: Given the timepoints in your sample data, it is impossible to determine where exactly the extra NA observations should be filled in. Every observation is at a different timepoint, and there is no consistency in the intervals between them. So there is no automatic way to do this. Regarding the error: I tried it with your sample data and it worked perfectly. Make sure that mdyhms is a character string that is formatted everywhere in the same manner throughout the variable, and don't forget to transform first to POSIXct.

Comment: @Erica : even if you would define the intervals and put every timepoint in the interval where it belongs, some intervals still get 2 datapoints. Hence, there is no possible way of doing this.

Comment: @Joris Meys: As you've pointed out, some intervals get 2 observations. My idea was to define intervals and locate the observed variables in the corresponding interval. And when 2 observations are located in the same interval consider the MEAN. I was trying several forms but I failed to do it. I guess I'll have to do that manually. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Erica : That's already quite something different. That's actually a lot more doable than your initial question. If you adapt the question, I'll check what I can find.

Comment: @Joris Meys: it almost works as I need! I did some changes in order to TS starts with the first observation (and not with NA).          I only need one more thing: I would like the time of the TS starts with a value equal to the correspondent fraction of the first observ. and not 1 (in this case in 1.8125). Thanks!

Comment: @Erica : just do it as I did, and drop the first NA observations. Or set start=1.8125 in the ts command (see the ts help files). If this answer is what you need, you can mark it as correct by using the V on the left.